# Angular RouterStub: returning url property

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a **router stub** with the method `navigate`, as code below:

```
@Injectable()
export class RouterStub {
    public events: any;

    public setRoutesRecognized(routesRecognized: RoutesRecognized) {
      this.events = new Observable(observer => {
        observer.next(routesRecognized);
        observer.complete();
      });
    }

    public navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras) { }
}
```

Thing is I need to return the URL of the navigation. I'm having really hard time by mocking stuff in `Angular`.

For example, I have to iterate through items and check for the URL:

```
private selectTabBasedOnActiveRoute() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; i++) {
      if (this.router.url.indexOf(this.tabs[i].url) > 0) {
          this.selectedTabIndex = i;
      }
    }
}
```

That is my test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    activatedRouteStub = new ActivatedRouteStub();
    activatedRouteStub.testParamMap = { customerId: 1 };

    routerStub = new RouterStub();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ContractModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(contractRoutes)
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteStub } ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContractTabListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ContractService);
});

it("should select 'Customer' tab when navigating to empty route", fakeAsync(() => {
    // Act
    routerStub.navigate([""]);

    fixture.detectChanges(); // this calls selectTabBasedOnActiveRoute

    tick();

    // Assert
    expect(component.selectedTabIndex).toBe(0);
}));
```

How to I return `this.router.url` from my **RouterStub**?

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I'm sharing what I did for now. I don't know if it's right as I didn't find any reference:

```
@Injectable()
export class RouterStub {
  public events: any;

  public url;

  public setRoutesRecognized(routesRecognized: RoutesRecognized) {
    this.events = new Observable(observer => {
      observer.next(routesRecognized);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }

  public navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras) {
    this.url = commands[0];
  }
}
```